# Protected should need more rep to answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, protected-questions

Today I was looking at the last page in newest for all questions tagged "iPhone" and saw [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c) And then I read about the "protected by" state it was in. But, 10 reputation doesn't seem enough.

I don't how much would be enough, but a lot of people get 10 very easily, because all they need to do is ask 1 question with 2 up-votes. I've seen a lot of people answer "Thanks" and what not as their first answer because they have never answered anything here and believe that is a forum.

To throw a number out their I would say 75 should be the new standard for the rep. Maybe it's slightly to high, but I don't believe 10 is enough. Your thoughts?

Comment: +1 2 question upvotes or 1 answer upvote are/is enough to meet this criterion, and I don't see how that instantly teaches a new user *not* to post 'thanks', 'me too' etc answers. I propose 50, the same limit for posting comments.

Comment: *'I've seen a lot of people answer "Thanks" [...] because they have never answered anything here and believe that is a forum.'* They do, and they get corrected. Gently for the most part.

Comment: @dmckee Sure, but what's the point of protected if not to avoid needing to have those corrections?

Comment: @Michael: I've never understood what "protected" was supposed to do, but I address the forum-mentality type "answers" all over the place and don't see this as helping much.

Comment: @dmckee: This is intended to address google-drive-by comments (i.e. from non-regulars) which amassed on some questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the blog entry.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/

This is only to prevent drive-by answers by new, unregistered users.

edit: the protected status really isn't right for this question, IMO. Locked or closed would be more appropriate (both of which prevent *any* answers)

Comment: Even though you have a point, I know some people who use forums and sites like this once and leave. Then by chance they come back to an important question and realizing they have an account they spam it with "thanks".